# Using form combo box to change server name of connection string

Tags: ms-access

I am setting up an access form to enter the parameters for a query, as well as select the needed database server to connect to. This will need to be run to gather data from multiple buildings, each of which has a different server name. All table names and fields are universal.

I have the server names, universal ID and PW, database name, network name, and port used to connect to the SQL servers. All are the same for all buildings, except server name. So only the server name will need to be changed in the connection string. All of this info is saved in a table.

I've read several posts from stack and other sites but cant quite get anything to work.

What I want to be able to do is to use a combo box to select the building name that I want to connect to, and have that combo box output the server name for that building. (This I know how to do within the properties window) And then have the VBA code update the linked tables to the new server.

What I do not know/understand is how to pass the combo box output into a VBA variable to be used in the connection string, nor write the code to update the connection string. Most of what I have found has been how to change DSN to DSN-less, or change specific tables. I want to update all the linked tables at once.

Id like to understand generally how the code works, so any ELI5 comments are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function to create a connection string:

```
Public Function ConnectionString( _
    ByVal Hostname As String, _
    ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal Username As String, _
    ByVal Password As String) _
    As String

' Create ODBC connection string from its variable elements.
' 2016-04-24. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const AzureDomain   As String = ".windows.net"
    Const OdbcConnect   As String = _
        "ODBC;" & _
        "DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;" & _
        "Description=Your Application;" & _
        "APP=Microsoft® Access;" & _
        "SERVER={0};" & _
        "DATABASE={1};" & _
        "UID={2};" & _
        "PWD={3};" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=No;"

    Dim FullConnect     As String

    If Right(Hostname, Len(AzureDomain)) = AzureDomain Then
        ' Azure SQL connection.
        ' Append servername to username.
        Username = Username & "@" & Split(Hostname)(0)
    End If
    FullConnect = OdbcConnect
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{0}", Hostname)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{1}", Database)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{2}", Username)
    FullConnect = Replace(FullConnect, "{3}", Password)

    ConnectionString = FullConnect

End Function
```

And here is a function to relink the tables and pass-trough queries:

```
Public Function AttachSqlServer( _
    ByVal Hostname As String, _
    ByVal Database As String, _
    ByVal Username As String, _
    ByVal Password As String) _
    As Boolean

' Attach all tables linked via ODBC to SQL Server or Azure SQL.
' 2016-04-24. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.

    Const cstrQuery1    As String = "_Template"
    Const cstrQuery2    As String = "_TemplateRead"
    Const cstrQuery3    As String = "VerifyConnection"

    Const cstrDbType    As String = "ODBC"
    Const cstrAcPrefix  As String = "dbo_"

    Dim dbs             As DAO.Database
    Dim tdf             As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strConnect      As String
    Dim strName         As String

    On Error GoTo Err_AttachSqlServer

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strConnect = ConnectionString(Hostname, Database, Username, Password)

    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        strName = tdf.Name
        If Asc(strName) <> Asc("~") Then
            If InStr(tdf.Connect, cstrDbType) = 1 Then
                If Left(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix)) = cstrAcPrefix Then
                    tdf.Name = Mid(strName, Len(cstrAcPrefix) + 1)
                End If
                tdf.Connect = strConnect
                tdf.RefreshLink
                Debug.Print Timer, tdf.Name, tdf.SourceTableName, tdf.Connect
                DoEvents
            End If
        End If
    Next
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery1).Connect = strConnect
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery2).Connect = strConnect
    dbs.QueryDefs(cstrQuery3).Connect = strConnect
    Debug.Print "Done!"

    AttachSqlServer = True

Exit_AttachSqlServer:
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Function

Err_AttachSqlServer:
    Call ErrorMox
    Resume Exit_AttachSqlServer

End Function
```

This should get you going.